# How do Google and Facebook implement and create the preview link functionality?

Tags: python, image, webpage-screenshot

Google, Facebook and some others now have a preview link functionality where you can view a "screenshot" of say a website's home page. Are there any suggestions how I can achieve this?

Specifically I'd like to be able to grab a screenshot (a la iPhone screen shot) and make it available as an image such as a jpg or png.

I want to do this from python if possible.

Comment: Interesting question, How to screenshot a web page by code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're using the service [Bluga](http://webthumb.bluga.net/home), it's not too expansive and is pretty easy to implement. If you don't like that [there are many other services available](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=sv&source=hp&q=website+screenshot&aq=0&aqi=g5&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=ed66c7602eea7772).

Comment: Thanks. Tried out Bluga which was easy to use but too slow for my immediate use as I need a bit now realtime so to speak. Checking out the alternatives now as well.

Comment: I don't think you will find anything realtime, there are too much processing to capture a screenshot. The service will have to put your request in a queue, a screenshot drone will have to load the website, take the screenshot, save it and send it/the link to you.

Comment: Update: I ended up using phantomjs to do this. A few things to look out for though: We had to work through a few issues to get a reasonable render time. The dependencies for this are ridiculous to the extreme - QT & X window dependencies. All things considered the screenshots are perfect and rendered in fractions of a second locally. If anybody is interested in the details drop me a line.

Comment: @znarkus yes it will capture flash. You need to set load-plugins=yes . I have not had the need and my environment was Linux. I have read anecdotal evidence of it being a bit inconsistant on windows but I'd guess if it worked at all on windows then tit might be just timing issues.

Answer (score 3):

For that you have to run a separate web browser and then save the image in the required format. You may try a headless web stack like [phantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org) as a separate process and capture its out put as image.

There are several web services that provide this functionality like [WebSnapr](http://www.websnapr.com/)

Comment: Thanks for that. I was thinking that this (phantomJS) might be a way to try but if somebody else has done the work I'll happily use that. Websnapr looks good but I have to get it to work sensible with iPhone sizing.

Comment: Update: I ended up using phantomjs to do this. A few things to look out for though: We had to work through a few issues to get a reasonable render time. The dependencies for this are ridiculous to the extreme - QT & X window dependencies. All things considered the screenshots are perfect and rendered in fractions of a second locally. If anybody is interested in the details drop me a line.

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery Preview](https://github.com/embedly/jquery-preview) may also help. It is really similar to Facebook's preview