# How do I add weblink previews like Facebook to my Android application?

Tags: android, preview

I have googled the heck out of this but I could not find any pointers. So any help would be great.

I am trying to implement a link preview for my users in a feed stream like Facebook on an Android native app as below!!

[image]

I am looking for solutions which require least amount of data usage by the user and hence reducing loading time so that this ca be accomplished cleanly.
Do I have to store the image, title and description data on my own server??

Please HELP!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution in a blog. It stores the image thumbnails in the cache. However I am worried about the memory leaks.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/

Please check this out and tell me how we can tackle memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a third-party service like ThumbnailApp, which I [wrote about here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921611/a-way-to-implement-facebooks-functionality-of-link-sharing/18478898#18478898) for a similar question, except you would need to use the HTTP API and not the JavaScript SDK. There are also other services like ShrinkTheWeb but I'm not sure they give you the title / description.